# Drag And Drop events are interrupting smooth motion of GUI when scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, double-buffering

I have a `splitContainer` control.
 inside one of the splitContainer panels there is a `FlowlayoutPanel` configured with `AutoScroll=True`.
the FlowLayoutPanel contains ~200 controls (so the user must scroll in order to communicate with all the controls). 
 each control is made of FlowLayoutPanel parent that has 3 child's of FlowLayoutPanels inside him, each child has 2 `Label` child's inside him.
all the Labels invoke "Drag" Events:

```
    private void Vcont_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       System.Windows.Forms.Control c = sender as System.Windows.Forms.Control;
       c.DoDragDrop(c, System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    private void Vcont_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects.All;
    }
```

the `Form` is set to `DoubleBuffered=True` and i wrote extension methods for each control (splitContainer,flowlayoutpanels and labels) in order to set the `DoubleBuffered` Property to true , for example:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
   public static void DoubleBuffered_FlPanel(this FlowLayoutPanel fp, bool setting)
    {
        Type type = fp.GetType();
        PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        pi.SetValue(fp, setting, null);
    }
}
```

**My question:** UX experience is negatively affected because controls are flickering and screen get stack while scrolling and it feels poor quality.
i have discovered that if i`m commenting the Drag&Drop events, GUI behave drastically better. **how can i invoke those events for each control without damaging the user experience?**

thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running a profiler against your application? My feeling is that `DoubleBuffered_FlPanel` is going to be your problem. That method there is millions of times slower than anything else in your application. Reflection should NEVER be done on your UI thread.

Comment: @Aron I had that concern, i will diagnose it, thank you for your advice and for the lighting up: Reflection should NEVER be done on your UI thread

Comment: Why are you using the MouseEnter event to initiate D&D.  The typical method is to use the MouseDown event.  I ran a quick test using MouseEnter, and it is hit repeatedly while the mouse is within the control.  It appears that initiating the drag causes the Mouse to leave the control.  These multiple event firings are likely a part of your issue.

Comment: @TnTinMn that is exactly the conclusion that i had this morning, changed it to `MouseEnter` event and everything is working properly. that is the answer, please write it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the MouseEnter event to initiate drag & drop. The typical method is to use the MouseDown event.

I ran a quick test using MouseEnter, and it is hit repeatedly while the mouse is within the control. It appears that initiating the drag causes the Mouse to leave the control. These multiple event firings are likely a large part of your issue.